# How to change state in a handler

Tags: reactjs, recompose

I have a React project and it's using Recompose. Let's say I have a Form, and I supply a 'withHandler' to be used for ..

How can I also change the state of the React component when the Form is submitted?

Comment: It would help if you posted an example and code for what you're talking about.

Answer (score 0):

So let's say the form is submitted with a `button`, and we have a `onClick` attribute on the button.

It's a very simple example but hopefully shows you how you would update state with the `onClick`. Remember, this an attribute that can be applied on HTML elements. You can read about it [the onClick attribute here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ev_onclick.asp).

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import Component from "react-component-component";

class Button extends Component {
  state = {
    counter: 0
  };

  handleButtonClick = () => {
    this.setState({
      counter: this.state.counter + 1
    });
  };

  getButton = () => {
    const { text } = this.props;

    return (
      <button
        onClick={this.handleButtonClick}
      >
        {text}
        {this.state.counter}
      </button>
    );
  };

  render() {
    return <div>{this.getButton()}</div>;
  }
}

render(
  <Button text="press me to increase counter: " />,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

The following can be seen here: https://codesandbox.io/s/ly11qv0vr7

There is also a very good example of react documentation regarding handling events. You can read about [handling events in react here](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html). I believe the above link will provide you all the information needed to be able to handle a form being submitted.